# The right way to manage user privileges (user hierarchy)

Tags: database, database-design, orm

I want to allow users of my application to add sub-users and set privileges for what each sub-user is allowed to view or do.

My ideas is to have a separate PRIVILEGES table, like this:

```
+-----------------+--------+
|privilege        |  value |
+-----------------+--------+
|create sub users |    1   |
|edit own profile |    2   |
|add new site     |    3   |
|delete site      |    4   |
+-----------------+--------+
```

Then when the main user selects privileges update the sub users privilege column with the value, for example:

```
+--------------+-----------+
|user_id       | privilege |
+--------------+-----------+
|user_1        |     4     | 
|user_2        |     2     |
|user_3        |     1     |
|user_4        |     2     |
+--------------+-----------+
```

But the values do not give unique amounts. For example:

```
privileges
1 -> create sub users
+
2 -> edit own profile
= privilege 3 (create sub users, edit own profile)
```

but also there is another privilege for value 3 (add new site) so this will not work.

**So my question is: How do I make any possible privilege combination unique?**

Is there a smarter way to manage privileges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep this as one column, use `base 2` placeholders.

```
1 - represents priv 1
2 - represents priv 2
4 - represents priv 3
8 - represents priv 4
16 - represents priv 5
32 - represents priv 6
```

Then you can take a modulus of each to determine if they have that priv.

So..

```
3 = priv 1 and priv 2
9 = priv 1 and priv 4

63 = all privs.
```

and so on.

It may be simpler to just have your priv table allow multiple entries per user.

EDIT:  If you still wish to use the single column to store priv, add another column that stores who gave the permission.

But... I'd still suggest storing each priv separately.
Create a table with a **combined primary key on priv, user_id, and grantor**.
The combined primary key will ensure that each priv is unique so you don't need to check before inserting.  To create a combined primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE priv ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id,grantor,priv_id);
```

Then to add or reset a priv, `REPLACE INTO priv (user_id,grantor,priv_id) VALUES (?,?,?)`

To delete a priv for a user, `DELETE FROM priv WHERE user_id = ? AND priv_id = ?`

To delete all priv for a user, `DELETE FROM priv WHERE user_id = ?`

To delete all sub users for a grantor... `DELETE FROM priv WHERE grantor = ?`

Getting all privs for a user within a grantor: `SELECT * FROM priv WHERE user_id = ? AND grantor = ?`

Comment: One other question: Say super_user 1 and super_user 2 both add sub_user 1. How would you map this in the database?

Comment: by the way. There is only one users table, where both sub_users and super_users are stored.

Comment: Yes, if I understand correctly, this will allows, sub_user 1 to be a member of as many accounts as needed correct?

Comment: yes.  I guess grantor would be account_id if that's the terminology you are using.

Comment: Thanks again, Daren, you have given me many idea/options. Now I can get to work :)

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this without exponentiation?

Comment: Building it up is addition.  Tearing it down is modulus.  No exponentiation the way I did it.  I'd still recommend using a separate table for this.